# WiFi keeps dying on a Dell XPS 13

Tags: linux, wifi, broadcom

On my Dell XPS 13, the WiFi regularely dies. Sometimes after minutes. Sometimes after hours. After it died, I have to deactivate Networking. And reenable it. For example in the Linux Mint Menu. Sometimes this helps, sometimes even a reboot does not help. On the command line, it has helped to unmount and mount the wl module:

```
modprobe -r wl
modprobe wl
```

"lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network" gives me this:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Dell BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0019]
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
Region 0: Memory at f7200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Region 2: Memory at f7000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=2 PME-
```

In the output of "dmesg -T", I often see this:

```
[Sat Sep 10 11:30:35 2016] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[Sat Sep 10 11:30:35 2016] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[Sat Sep 10 11:30:35 2016] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[Sat Sep 10 11:30:35 2016] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[Sat Sep 10 11:30:35 2016] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[Sat Sep 10 11:30:35 2016] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[Sat Sep 10 11:30:35 2016] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[Sat Sep 10 11:30:35 2016] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[Sat Sep 10 11:30:35 2016] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[Sat Sep 10 11:30:35 2016] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[Sat Sep 10 11:30:35 2016] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
```

"lshw -C network" gives me this:

```
*-network               
description: Wireless interface
product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Broadcom Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: wlp2s0
version: 03
serial: ...
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=... latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
resources: irq:19 memory:f7200000-f7207fff memory:f7000000-f71fffff
```

Here is the output of lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
wl                   6447104  0
cfg80211              565248  1 wl
rfcomm                 69632  2
bnep                   20480  2
binfmt_misc            20480  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
hid_multitouch         20480  0
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
dell_wmi               16384  0
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
uvcvideo               90112  0
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
dell_laptop            20480  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
snd_soc_ssm4567        16384  0
kvm                   540672  1 kvm_intel
snd_soc_rt286          36864  0
snd_soc_rl6347a        16384  1 snd_soc_rt286
snd_soc_core          212992  2 snd_soc_ssm4567,snd_soc_rt286
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
dell_led               16384  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
mei_me                 36864  0
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_rt286,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
lpc_ich                24576  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
shpchp                 36864  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
elan_i2c               36864  0
snd                    81920  23 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
soundcore              16384  1 snd
int3403_thermal        16384  0
intel_vbtn             16384  0
soc_button_array       16384  0
dw_dmac                16384  0
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
8250_dw                16384  0
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
tpm_crb                16384  0
int3402_thermal        16384  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  3 int3402_thermal,processor_thermal_device,int3403_thermal
int3400_thermal        16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
intel_hid              16384  0
acpi_pad               20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  3 dell_wmi,intel_hid,intel_vbtn
acpi_als               16384  0
kfifo_buf              16384  1 acpi_als
industrialio           57344  2 acpi_als,kfifo_buf
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
btrfs                 987136  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              102400  1 btrfs
jitterentropy_rng      16384  0
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
algif_skcipher         20480  0
af_alg                 16384  1 algif_skcipher
dm_crypt               28672  2
dm_mirror              24576  0
dm_region_hash         24576  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
i915                 1208320  4
aesni_intel           167936  5
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
drm_kms_helper        147456  1 i915
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ahci                   36864  4
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
cryptd                 20480  4 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               126976  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   364544  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
wmi                    20480  2 dell_led,dell_wmi
video                  40960  3 i915,dell_wmi,dell_laptop
i2c_hid                20480  0
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
hid                   118784  2 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
fjes                   28672  0
```

Any ideas how to find the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the power management:

```
iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

To make it permanent , create a `power_off` file

```
nano /etc/pm/config.d/power_off
```

With the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

make it executable `chmod +x /etc/pm/config.d/power_off`

Then unload conflicting modules:

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

Or blacklist them under `etc/modprobe.d/`

Comment: Tried this now. I cannot see any difference in the behavior of the machine. The Wi-Fi keeps dying just like before.

Comment: Installing a new kernel version is the best way to solve this problem